# <asp:Button> event not firing when within element affected by jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am creating an ASP.NET with C# calendar application. When a user clicks on a day, I am using a [jQuery Popup Overlay](http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/) which will allow the user to add an 'appointment' and click a button to process the entered information in the codebehind.

The Popup overlay basically hides an HTML element and makes it visible when another element is clicked (great examples by following link above).

The Code:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonA" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" Text="Button A" />
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="Foo"></asp:Label>

<div id='slide'>        
    <div id="content">
        Content of the 'popup panel'
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonB" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" Text="Button B" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label.Text = "Bar"; 
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slide').popup({
        //options
    });
});
```

I tried adding the AutoPostBack="true" parameter to the buttons, but it doesn't make a difference (should be automatic regardless, correct?). I also tried adding the runat="server" parameter to the div elements, but that made the issue worse.

I am afraid that I don't understand the nature of the issue enough to provide more information than this - Sorry!

Comment: Is `slide` inside the `<form>` tag?

Comment: Yes sir, it works as expected if I comment out the JS

Comment: Getting any JS errors?  Can you edit your question to include the rendered button (in html)?

Comment: No JS errors. The button is rendered as: `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ButtonB" value="Button B" id="MainContent_ButtonB" autopostback="true">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the jQuery plugin is overriding the behaviour of the button. You could use the onclose callback from the URL you provided to have a function like so:

```
function() {
    __doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$ButtonB","");
}
```

Failing that, you could have another button outside the popup div which you do a `click()` event on manually during the `onclose` event of the popup, but that seems like a bit of a hack!

Comment: This resolved the issue! Thank you - elegant solution.